# Как корректно сделать выборку данных?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Написал я следующий код:

```
import pandas as pd
california_train = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_test.csv')
california_test = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_train.csv')

california_train = california_train.drop('total_rooms', axis=1)
california_test = california_test.drop('total_rooms', axis=1)

if california_train.isnull().any().any():
  california_train.fillna(california_train.mean(), inplace = True)
else:
  pass

if california_test.isnull().any().any():
  california_test.fillna(california_test.mean(), inplace = True)
else:
  pass

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

california_trainsc = scaler.fit_transform(california_train)
california_testsc = scaler.fit_transform(california_test)
```

И вот пришёл черёд делать разделение данных на признаки и целевую переменную при помощи модуля train_test_split и соответствующей функции train_test_split(). Мне дано задание, по которому в качестве целевой переменной необходимо использовать столбец median_house_value. Я перепробовал несколько способов это сделать, но ни один из них не сработал. Никак не могу вникнуть, как же это разбивка правильно делается. Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вообще-то train_test_split() не делит разделение на "на признаки и целевую переменную". Он как бы предназначен для совсем других целей. Вы уж уточните и если надо помощь -  то сформулируйте корректно вопрос.